# Compare folders using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, compare

Edit: Editing the question with more details:

I'm working on comparing two huge folders and figuring out which files are common in both the folders. 
MSDN has the program using LINQ to solve it : article [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546137.aspx)

However there is a problem which I'm trying to fix.

Let's say I have two folders. FolderA and FolderB. FolderA and Folder B has two subfolders 1 and 2.

- C:\FolderA\1\a.aspx
- C:\FolderA\2\b.aspx
- C:\FolderB\1\a.aspx
- C:\FolderB\1\b.aspx

a.aspx and b.aspx are identical in both FolderA and FolderB. Note than b.aspx exist in different subfolders though.

Current Result:
C:\FolderA\1\a.aspx
C:\FolderA\2\b.aspx

I expect the result matches to be just C:\FolderA\1\a.aspx because it match with the folder structure and also the file is identical.

Would I be able to modify the FileCompare class to perform the comparison of files which lies in the same directory structure?

Or

What changes should I make to make sure the comparison is done correctly.

Thanks!
Sanjeev

Comment: I think you need to be more specific about exactly what you're asking about here.

Comment: It actually wasn't that hard to figure out what he meant once you opened the sample code from the article he linked to...

Comment: Edited the question to be more clear. Sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this work, you will need to adjust how the `Equals()` function operates. My suggestion is as follows:

#### Step 1 - Make `path` variables available to the `Equals()` method:

```
class CompareDirs
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // Create two identical or different temporary folders  
            // on a local drive and change these file paths. 
            string pathA = @"C:\TestDir";
            string pathB = @"C:\TestDir2";
...
```

becomes

```
class CompareDirs
    {
        private string pathA, pathB;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // Create two identical or different temporary folders  
            // on a local drive and change these file paths. 
            pathA = @"C:\TestDir";
            pathB = @"C:\TestDir2";
...
```

#### Step 2 - Change `Equals()` method to consider this information:

I suggest using `.replace(pathA, pathB)` to enable the directories of the files to be compared as if the path was the same. Thus any files that are in the same subdirectory structure will be have the same directory overall (after the replace operation has been performed).

```
    public bool Equals(System.IO.FileInfo f1, System.IO.FileInfo f2)
    {
        return (f1.Name == f2.Name &&
                f1.Length == f2.Length &&
                f1.DirectoryName.replace(pathA, pathB) == f2.DirectoryName.replace(pathA, pathB) );
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey. But I don't see .replace method available for f1.Directory

Comment: Oops! That should have been `f1.DirectoryName.replace()` and likewise for f2. Updated.

Comment: Great. That works! A small change I had to make is re-assigning the path variables again in the FileCompare class as I couldn't declare the variables outside the main and re-use them.